# Replacing old outlet, has blue, black, red and white wires

Tags: receptacle

I have an old outlet that trips the break when I plug in a space heater.
The outlet has four wires, blue, black, red and white. What do I do when i replace the outlet?
I'm going to replace the old outlet with a new GFCI.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEgDE.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEgDE.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KTkj.jpg)[image]

Comment: Do you think the outlet is defective? What good does a GFCI do for you? Is your overloading the breaker then it's still going to trip. A space heater is notoriously power-hungry and you cannot plug in much else when using one.

Comment: Why is there a blue wire going to the neutral side of that outlet?

Comment: What else is on the circuit?  A space heater is a HUGE load that dominates a circuit, needing 60-80% of its capacity, and will always trip the breaker if any other load of any size is on the circuit.

Comment: that's a commercial grade outlet,  it's probably still good.

Comment: Yes, what else is on the circuit, how many watts is the heater, and does the breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: The circuit is powering an automated sprinkler system, a security system and six other bedroom and hallway outlets. Sounds like the problem is the load.

Comment: The typical space heater will consume 1500 watts or roughly 80% of a 120v 15A circuit's maximum amperage. You should avoid using more than 80% of a circuit's available power for extended periods of time. When the space heater is running then it really should be the only thing running on that circuit except for maybe a few LED lights. FWIW, my basement dehumidifier ran on the same circuit as my space heater for months and the breaker never tripped. Not sure if I should be worried or lauding my appliances for efficient energy usage.